# Mongoose update subdocument array with subdocument value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this one:

```
{
 _id:ObjectId('111'),
 products:[
  {
   _id:ObjectId('aaa'),
   quantity:2,
   price:800
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to update price field by multiplying it with quantity field ie (2 * 800) of which the result gets updated/assigned to price. (as for this example price gets updated to 1600).

**Document after Update :**

```
{
 _id:ObjectId('111'),
 products:[
  {
   _id:ObjectId('aaa'),
   quantity:2,
   price:1600  //the updated field by multiplying the initial 800 * 2
  }
 ]
}
```

My query for selecting is like this below:

```
    Shop.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id": '111, "products._id": 'aaa' }
    )
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it's a multi step process. Query the main document, get the array element, update the array element, the save the main document (which includes array too)

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah your solution looks quite impressive... Is it less expensive than using $ operators and looping the products array like how whoami suggested in the second answer?

Comment: My answer requires findById which causes an extra db access, but since finding by id is very fast, it has almost no performance penalty. I have no idea about the performance of solution of whoami.

Answer (score 3):

As @Casey suggested in the comments, you can do this in multi step, find the shop, find the product, change product price, save the shop.

```js
router.patch("/shops/:shopId/:productId", async (req, res) => {
  const { shopId, productId } = req.params;

  let shop = await Shop.findById(shopId);

  if (!shop) return res.status(400).send("Shop not found");

  const productIndex = shop.products.findIndex((p) => p._id.toString() === productId);

  if (productIndex < 0) return res.status(400).send("Product not found in shop");

  let product = shop.products[productIndex];

  product.price *= product.quantity;

  shop = await shop.save();

  res.send(shop);
});
```

Let's say you have this existing shop with two products:

```
{
    "_id": "5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d0",
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d2",
            "quantity": 2,
            "price": 800
        },
        {
            "_id": "5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d1",
            "quantity": 3,
            "price": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to update the price with the `"_id": "5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d2"`, we send a patch request to the url `http://your base url/shops/5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d0/5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d2`

The output will be like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d0",
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d2",
            "quantity": 2,
            "price": 1600  => UPDATED
        },
        {
            "_id": "5eb85ab17c2bfb3e2cfc15d1",
            "quantity": 3,
            "price": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Amani I will be happy if you can at least upvote this answer, it answers your question.

Comment: I have upvoted it. Your solution looks amazing, finding an index, updating the value and save it. With no looping the products array, I really think that this is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

On MongoDB version >= `4.2` as you can execute [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in updates, try below query :

```
Shop.update(
  /** Remember to convert input strings to type `ObjectId()` prior to querying */
  { _id: ObjectId("111"), "products._id": ObjectId("aaa") },
  /** This aggregation pipeline will re-create `products` array,
   *  if condition is met for an object then price will be multiplied & price field is merged to original object & pushed back to `products` array, 
   *  if condition is not met actual object is pushed back to array */
  [
    {
      $set: {
        products: {
          $map: {
            input: "$products",
            in: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$$this._id", ObjectId("aaa")] },
                {
                  $mergeObjects: [ "$$this", { price: { $multiply: ["$$this.quantity", "$$this.price"] }}]
                },
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But instead of looping using $map, since _id 'aaa' is already found from our filter in `products._id": ObjectId("aaa")` (hence we can get the specific item in products array), isn't there just a simple way of doing this using $set? something like `{ "$set": { "$price":{$multiply: ["$$this.quantity", "$$this.price"]} } }` or maybe `{ "$set": { "$price":{$multiply: ["$quantity", "$price"]} } }` ?

Comment: @Amani : what you’re talking about is ‘$’ positional operator unfortunately which you can’t use in this case..

Comment: Got it. I have tried it and it works greatly. (though looping on products looked somewhat expensive if the array has so many items). I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Amani : I believe there is no other better way to do it & it's better than doing two DB calls - one to read nd other to update, I guess you might end-up doing almost the same even in code. So better take advantage of new option of using aggregation pipeline in updates..